# Не могу создать графический интерфейс по простой задаче. Почему-то нужный текст не печатается в текстовом поле

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Задание 1')
root.geometry('300x500')
K1 = Label(text='Введите номер дня года (от 1 до 356):')
K = Entry(width=20)
Lbl = Label(bg='white', fg='black', width=30)
btn = Button(bg='red', text='Результат', font=40)
lb = Label(text="Номер дня недели", font=30)
def dni_goda(event):
    k = int(K.get())
    n = k % 7
    Lbl['text'] = str(n)
btn.bind('Button-1>', dni_goda)
K1.pack()
K.pack()
lb.pack(pady=(30,0))
Lbl.pack()
btn.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Условия задачи: дни недели пронумерованы следующим образом: 0 – воскресенье, 1 – понедельник, 2 – вторник, …… 6 – суббота. Дано целое число K, лежащее в диапазоне [1; 365]. Определить номер дня недели для K-го дня года, если известно, что в этом году 1 января было понедельником.

Comment: это просто - `btn.bind('<Button-1>', dni_goda)` больше вас ничего не смущает в этом коде?

Comment: Вообще, привязку функции к кнопке лучше делать через параметр command кнопки, а не через событие, а то кнопка будет залипать.